# Postgres massive UPSERT not wasting sequence numbers

Tags: postgresql, sequence, upsert

I have a too complicated task for me, and hope someone can help me :)

I have two different structures, containing data about products:

1.

- **products** with *product_id*, *brand_id* (products that I have)
- **products_sku** with *product_id*, *sku_id*, *vendor_code* (SKUs for products)
- **products_avail** with *sku_id*, *scheme_id*, *quantity* (availability for each product sku and scheme)

2. 

- **products_external** with *product_id_e*, *brand_id_e*, *vendor_code_e*, *sku_id_e*
- **products_avail_external** with *product_id_e*, *quantity_e*, *scheme_id_e*

Each SKU identified by (*brand_id*, *vendor_code*) pair, so one product from (2) corresponds to one SKU from (1). Also I can have several availability entries for different schemes. Availability records can count up to tens of millions records.

Field *sku_id_e* in (2) updates with cron task, so if it defined (i.e. not zero) - I can find corresponding record in (1).

I need to get all records from (2) with *sku_id_e* defined, group them by (*sku_id_e*, *scheme_id_e*) and make a set of records in (1), so one records will contain SUM(*quantity*) of all records with some (*sku_id_e*, *scheme_id_e*).

I can do UPSERT but in this case I will waste sequence numbers (which is problem in my case because request will be executed relatively frequently and on massive number of records).

I can use something like ON EMPTY or NOT EXISTS, but this is too complicated for me to combine in one request.

I can just select both datasets and make matching programmatically, but this is definitely not best solution.

Can you help me with making SQL code that will update records in (1) or insert them if such records does not exists (not wasting sequence)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no problem wasting sequence values, because you define the column with data type `bigint`.

Comment: It is a problem in my case, too many rows, too many increments.
Despite of this, I just want to know the answer to learn something new :)

Comment: You could load the new data into a temporary table, delete the rows that already exist in your regular table and insert the rest. This is, however, subject to race conditions, so suspend concurrent data modifications.